# How easy is this proof that the circle cannot be squared?

Tags: geometry, circles, curves

It is well-known that a disc can't be cut into finitely many pieces and reassembled into a square of the same area.  This is Tarski's famous problem, except only allowing Jordan curve cuts. It seems obvious to me that in attempting to do so, the exposed convex edges of the perimeter of the circle can only be eliminated, by cutting corresponding segments of concave curves to fit against it.  But so doing is guaranteed to generate new off-cuts with new edges having equally convex curves of total length $2\pi$.

Therefore the $2\pi$ length convex curve of the circle's perimeter can never be eliminated.  This is a simple proof which has always satisfied me.  How difficult is it to turn this into a rigorous proof?

I can imagine that we would start by defining the set of all exposed edges (initially the perimeter) and then prove that for any set of cuts, there will always be at least length $2\pi$ of exposed edges having curvature equal to the original circle.  Since squares have only straight exposed edges, the proof is complete.

Surely this can be a simple, elegant and obvious proof of something that for a long time was not accepted by many?

Comment: All constructions with compass and ruler can be translated into certain algebraic equations. It can be shown that $\pi$ cannot be expressed with any algenraic equations. Using other mechanical aids it may be possible to construct [$\pi$](http://www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Squaring_the_circle.html).

Comment: Note that the classical problem _does not say a thing about pieces_, no matter finitely many or not. It just asks to construct a square with certain area. Indeed, thinks of those [lunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_of_Hippocrates): they can be "squared", but not by cutting and reassembling.

Comment: Actually a disc *can* be "cut" into finitely many pieces and reassembled into a square of the same area.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_circle-squaring_problem -- but note the meaning of the word "cut"....

Comment: Wouldn't any such attempted proof necessarily apply also to any other region with curved boundary, such as for example the lune of Hippocrates, which famously *can* be squared?

Comment: @BarryCipra fully aware of that, but cuts not obeying Jordan curve boundaries are not necessarily any cut in the conventional sense of the notion.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I think my method would prove that the lune of Hippocrates requires infinite pieces.

Comment: @RobertFrost, it might help if you edited the question to make clear what you mean by the problem of "squaring the circle," because some of the comments assume it refers to the classic compass-and-straightedge construction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your idea - the edge of the circle needs to be eliminated because it is *strictly* convex, but I could certainly match the perimeter to a shape which has one arc to match the perimeter, but is otherwise polygonal. (Or I could do really nasty things with the remainder of the boundary of the piece I use to match, such as using non-rectifiable curves, where the notions of the proof seem irrelevant)

Comment: @Franky_GTH  The OP's unfortunate (inadvertent? advertent?) wording of "squaring a circle" has mislead you.  This is not a question about compass straight-edge constructions, but an entirely different type of problem (apparently also called circle squaring).

Comment: @MiloBrandt yes you can cut a piece having an edge to fit to some segment of the curve, but by so doing the piece you cut it from will always have a new curve created on it equal to the original segment.

Comment: @fleablood yes, sorry about the ambiguity, but 'circle squaring' problem does seem to be the name used for this type of translation from circle to square too.